# Error while Trying to modify Global variable using global keyword from the a function

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am trying to modify a global variable from a function using the global keyword But when I try to do so I am getting the error " "SyntaxError: name 'a' is used prior to global declaration"

```
a=10 ## Global variable

def Global_modify():
    a=19
    print(a)
    global a
    a=11
    print(a)
```

Expected Result : 19  11

Error:"SyntaxError: name 'a' is used prior to global declaration"

Comment: The first line declares a local variable a instead of using the global a.

Answer (score 1):

You have to declare `a` as global in the function before modifying it within the function. So your code should look like:

```
a=10 ## Global variable

def Global_modify():
    global a
    a=19
    print(a)
    a=11
    print(a)
```

Now, even if you ask for the value of `a` outside of the function, you will get whatever value you defined in the function.

Answer (score 0):

To avoid the SyntaxError exception, you will not be able to use the global declaration. You can still access global variables, however:

```
a=10 ## Global variable

def Global_modify():
    a=19
    print(a)
    globals()['a'] = 11

Global_modify()
print(a)

19
11
```